# Flutter image_picker permission can't find a valid activity to handle the request

Tags: android, image, flutter, imagepicker

I am using image_picker ^0.6.4 for get image from gallery and camera.
But the error when first installed and first asking for permission access.

*E/FilePickerDelegate(20097): Can't find a valid activity to handle the request. Make sure you've a file explorer installed.*

This normally when the application is restarted.

Comment: Please review your question. it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

If You are using 'file_picker' along with 'image_picker' in your pubspec.yaml file, change file_picker version. In my case I have changed file_picker: ^1.5.1 to file_picker: 1.4.3+2 then it worked.